# Does window.navigator.getGamepads() in Dart work?

Tags: dart

Calling `window.navigator.getGamepads()` returns a valid list of `Gamepad` objects, but the axes and buttons properties are always `null`.

The index and ID properties are all valid though. Am I missing something or does it just not work yet?

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Gamepad.html

Comment: What browser are you trying it in? Dartium? What version?

Answer (score 1):

The Gamepad API works in dart, just not in the dartium browser (see [Issue 15119](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15119)).
If you need to use the API, either create a new browser launch, or right-click your html file and then click on 'Run as JavaScript'. Either of these solutions will launch in your standard browser.

Comment: That's interesting because @user3357834 reports success in Dartium (see discussion at the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395329 I starred the issue anyway.