# Using Gamepads in Google Dart

Tags: google-chrome, dart

I'm looking for code examples for the [Gamepad API for Google Dart](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/#dart-dom-html.Gamepad).

I've tried relying on the API doc directly and attempted to write out an instance for it.

```
//Gamepad Example:

Gamepad g = new Gamepad();
g.id.toString(); // This doesn't seem to return anything...
```

If anyone has any code examples for this that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me :

```dart
import "dart:html";

main(){
  window.animationFrame.then(runAnimation);
}   

runAnimation(timestamp){

  var gamepads = window.navigator.getGamepads();

  for (var pad in gamepads)
  {
    if(pad != null){
      querySelector("#buttons").setInnerHtml("${pad.buttons.join(" ")}</br>${pad.axes.join(" ")}");
    }
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
}
```

Comment: What controller are you testing against?  I'm wondering if it's my hardware.

Comment: I am using a PS4 controller emulated as a Xinput device (Xbox 360 controller).
I tried successfully with Dartium, chrome (dart2js). Firefox(dart2js) didn't worked but i think the gamepads works differently on FF. Didn't tried further.

Comment: I can confirm this works, but only with an WIRED Xbox 360 controller!  PS3 fails even with a driver, and a NES retropad fails as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a gamepad to try but

```dart
Gamepad g = new Gamepad();
```

doesn't work because `Gamepade` has no public constructor.
Try

```dart
var gp = window.navigator.getGamepads();

//or

// haven't tried because I don't know how to provoke this event without a gamepad
window.on['gamepadconnected'].listen((e) {
  var gamepad = e.gamepad;
});
```

instead.
I get an empty list so I can't examine more.

see also:
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/Gamepad
- https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/gamepad/raw-file/default/gamepad.html

Comment: No luck thus far, but seems more logical than my first go at this.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If nothing else works you can try to use dart-js-interop (search for this tag here on SO)

Comment: I could but interop would work around Dart, I want to take advantage of the new Gamepad class.

Comment: I understand that, but there are some classes in 'dart:html' that are fully working and I just wanted to show that there are workarounds but the answer of @user3357834 indicates that it is working so this is obsolete anyway.